# How do I change number and bracket colors in the arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, ide

I recently personalized my arduino IDE (changed the background color, input text color, etc....) by going into the theme.txt file and replacing some hexadecimal values. I made the background black and the text lime green, but for some reason numbers and brackets still remain black, thus I can't see them against a black background. Anyone know how to fix this? I would really appreciate the help, got sick of looking at a white background when making sketches.

Sal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\lib\theme\syntax` there is file `default.xml` where I made some changes and the following lines are as follows:

```
  <style token="SEPARATOR" fg="ffffff" />
  <style token="LITERAL_NUMBER_DECIMAL_INT" fg="ffffff"/>
  <style token="LITERAL_NUMBER_FLOAT" fg="ffffff"/>
  <style token="LITERAL_NUMBER_HEXADECIMAL" fg="ffffff"/>
```

After this brackets and numbers occur white.

Comment: Ok i found the file and what I need to change. However, my computer opens the file in internet explorer. Do I need some software to open and edit xml files? If so, any suggestions?

Comment: Copy file and paste it to your desktop. Right click and select open with WordPad. Save after edit. Copy and  paste to original place. You are asked for admin rights. Give right by clicking option. Restart IDE.

Comment: In some windows you can select right click on file and edit as admin user.

Comment: I figured it out, wish I would have read your comment just above first haha would have saved me some trouble. I wound up using Visual Studio to change it. Thank you so much though for all the help